# SHParseDisplayName when path doesn't exists

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-shell

I'm developing a replacement for `IFileOpenDialog` and `IFileSaveDialog`.

I almost have it working (at least `IFileOpenDialog`), but when I want to return the `IShellItem` that represents the new filename (that the user has choosen to save in the `GetResult()` method), I can't get `SHParseDisplayName` working with this new filename. I always receive an error `"The system cannot find the file specified"`.

I will appreciate some examples or another solution maybe to my problem.

Edit:

```
    HRESULT CFileSaveDialogProxy::GetResult( __RPC__deref_out_opt IShellItem **ppsi)
    {
        //return m_Original->GetResult(ppsi);

        WCHAR pszPath[MAX_PATH] = {0};
        HRESULT hr = ERROR_CANCELLED;

        if (m_SelectedFiles.size() > 0)
        {
            QString s = m_SelectedFiles.at(0);
            s.replace(QString("/"),QString("\\"));
            s.toWCharArray(pszPath);

            //PCIDLIST_ABSOLUTE pIdL = ILCreateFromPath(pszPath);
            PIDLIST_ABSOLUTE pIdL = NULL;
            SFGAOF out;
            hr = SHParseDisplayName(pszPath,NULL,&pIdL,SFGAO_FILESYSTEM,&out);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                hr = SHCreateItemFromIDList(pIdL, IID_PPV_ARGS(ppsi));
            }
        }

        return hr;
    }
```

Comment: What is the edit about ? Your original attempt which exhibits the problem  ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use the `IBindCtx` parameter to pass additional data to the parser, in this case your own file metadata so `SHParseDisplayName()` will not try to access a real file to get the metadata.  This is described in the [`IShellFolder::ParseDisplayName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ishellfolder-parsedisplayname) and [`SHCreateItemFromParsingName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-shcreateitemfromparsingname) documentations:

> A pointer to a bind context used to pass parameters as inputs and outputs to the parsing function. These passed parameters are often specific to the data source and are documented by the data source owners. **For example, the file system data source accepts the name being parsed (as a [WIN32_FIND_DATA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/minwinbase/ns-minwinbase-win32_find_dataa) structure), using the [STR_FILE_SYS_BIND_DATA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/str-constants#STR_FILE_SYS_BIND_DATA) bind context parameter.** STR_PARSE_PREFER_FOLDER_BROWSING can be passed to indicate that URLs are parsed using the file system data source when possible. **Construct a bind context object using [CreateBindCtx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objbase/nf-objbase-createbindctx) and populate the values using [IBindCtx::RegisterObjectParam](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objidl/nf-objidl-ibindctx-registerobjectparam). See [Bind Context String Keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/str-constants) for a complete list of these.**

And outlined in detail on the MSDN "Old New Thing" blog:

[Creating a simple pidl: For the times you care enough to send the very fake](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130503-00/?p=4463)