# How to use SHCreateItemFromParsingName with names from the shell namespace?

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-shell

I am using [`SHCreateItemFromParsingName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762134.aspx) to turn a *path* into a [`IShellItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761144.aspx):

```
IShellItem ParseName(String path)
{
    IShellItem shellItem;

    HRESULT hr = SHCreateItemFromParsingName(path, null, IShellItem, out shellItem);
    if (Failed(hr)) 
        throw new ECOMException(hr);
    return shellItem;
}
```

> **Note**: A `IShellItem` was introduced around 2006 to provide a handy wrapper around the Windows 95-era `IShellFolder`+`pidl` constructs. You can even ask a `IShellItem` to cough up it's underlying `IShellFolder` and `pidl` with the `IParentAndItem.GetParentAndItem` interface and method.

## Different things have different display names

I can get ahold of some well-known locations in the shell namespace, and see their absolute *parsing* (`SIGDN_DESKTOPABSOLUTEPARSING`) and *editing* (`SIGDN_DESKTOPABSOLUTEEDITING`) display names:

| Path | Editing | Parsing |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C:\ | "C:" | "C:" |
| C:\Windows | "C:\Windows" | "C:\Windows" |
| Desktop | "Desktop" | "C:\Users\Ian\Desktop" |
| Computer | "This PC" | "::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}" |
| Recycle Bin | "Recycle Bin" | "::{645FF040-5081-101B-9F08-00AA002F954E}" |
| Documents Library | "Libraries\Documents" | "::{031E4825-7B94-4DC3-B131-E946B44C8DD5}\Documents.library-ms" " |
| Startup | "C:\Users\Ian\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup" | "C:\Users\Ian\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup" |

### How to parse them when the user types in them in?

I can use `IFileOpenDialog` to let the user select one of these folders. But i'd really like the user to be able to **type**

- *"C:\Users"*
- *"C:\Windows\Fonts"*
- *"This PC"*
- *"Recycle Bin"*
- *"Libraries"*
- *"Startup"*
- *"Fonts"*

and be able to parse it into an *`IShellItem`*.

The problem is that some of the paths are **not** parsed by `SHCreateItemFromParsingName`:

- **`SHCreateItemFromParsingName("C:\")`**: Parses
- **`SHCreateItemFromParsingName("C:\Windows")`**: Parses
- **`SHCreateItemFromParsingName("")`**: Parses *(but becomes "**This PC**")*
- **`SHCreateItemFromParsingName("This PC")`**: Fails
- **`SHCreateItemFromParsingName("Recycle Bin")`**: Fails
- **`SHCreateItemFromParsingName("Libraries")`**: Fails
- **`SHCreateItemFromParsingName("OneDrive")`**: Fails
- **`SHCreateItemFromParsingName("Libraries\Documents")`**: Fails
- **`SHCreateItemFromParsingName("Network")`**: Fails
- **`SHCreateItemFromParsingName("Startup")`**: Fails

Meanwhile, the *IFileOpenDialog* control that my program uses can parse them fine:

[image]

How can i parse the various special shell name places that a user might type in (that Windows Explorer and the IFileOpen dialog can parse) into an `IShellItem` for that folder?

The **real** question is that i want the user to be able to have a *recent MRU list* that contains things like:

- C:\Windows
- Recycle Bin
- This PC

and be able to parse them later.

Comment: Note that all the things that fail are immediately under the desktop. I'd guess that Explorer uses `IShellFolder::ParseDisplayName` on the desktop folder.

Comment: You can have 2 MRU lists. First will contain strings for UI ("This PC") and second will contain strings for parsing ("::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}"). And when user selects UI string you will work with corresponding parsing string.

Comment: This is basically a duplicate of the unsolved http://stackoverflow.com/q/37000602/3501 but this question is already higher quality IMHO.

Comment: Those aren't parsing names. They are display names.

Comment: Nitpick: IShellItem became public/documented in 2002 (XP.SP1). It was used internally in the Explorer task-pane in XP.RTM (AFAIK).

Comment: @RaymondChen Are you saying SHParseDisplayName would be able to parse these or is Explorer doing extra work?

Comment: Explorer is doing extra work. Basically, it looks for a child whose display name matches the value the user typed. SHParseDisplayName can only parse names that were meant to be parsed back (SHGDN_FORPARSING). If you ask for a display name, then the only way to find it again is to hunt for a match. (You can have multiple items with the same display name. Display names are ambiguous.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would be interesting to debug Explorer and see how it does it.

My suggestion is; if the initial parse fails, prepend `shell:` to the path string and try parsing it again with `SHParseDisplayName`. If you set [`STR_PARSE_SHELL_PROTOCOL_TO_FILE_OBJECTS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762592(v=vs.85).aspx) in the bind context you can also bind to special files. The shell: protocol is able to parse the internal/canonical name of special/known folders but I don't know if it also checks the display name.

Edit:

I had a chance to play around a bit now and the shell: prefix is not a huge improvement because it only checks the known folder canonical names:

```
PCWSTR paths[] = {
    TEXT("C:\\"),
    TEXT("C:\\Windows"),
    TEXT(""),
    TEXT("This PC"),
    TEXT("MyComputerFolder"), // Canonical KF name
    TEXT("Recycle Bin"),
    TEXT("RecycleBinFolder"), // Canonical KF name
    TEXT("Libraries"),
    TEXT("OneDrive"),
    TEXT("Libraries\\Documents"),
    TEXT("Network"),
    TEXT("NetworkPlacesFolder"), // Canonical KF name
    TEXT("Startup"),
};

OleInitialize(0);
INT pad = 0, fill, i;
for (i = 0; i < ARRAYSIZE(paths); ++i) pad = max(pad, lstrlen(paths[i]));
for (i = 1, fill = printf("%-*s | Original | shell:   |\n", pad, ""); i < fill; ++i) printf("-"); printf("\n");
for (i = 0; i < ARRAYSIZE(paths); ++i)
{
    WCHAR buf[MAX_PATH], *p1 = NULL, *p2 = NULL;
    IShellItem*pSI;
    HRESULT hr = SHCreateItemFromParsingName(paths[i], NULL, IID_IShellItem, (void**) &pSI);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) pSI->GetDisplayName(SIGDN_DESKTOPABSOLUTEPARSING, &p1), pSI->Release();
    wsprintf(buf, L"shell:%s", paths[i]);
    HRESULT hr2 = SHCreateItemFromParsingName(buf, NULL, IID_IShellItem, (void**) &pSI);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr2)) pSI->GetDisplayName(SIGDN_DESKTOPABSOLUTEPARSING, &p2), pSI->Release();
    wprintf(L"%-*s | %.8x | %.8x | %s\n", pad, paths[i], hr, hr2, p2 && *p2 ? p2 : p1 ? p1 : L"");
    CoTaskMemFree(p1), CoTaskMemFree(p2);
}
```

gives me this output:

```
                    | Original | shell:   |
-------------------------------------------
C:\                 | 00000000 | 80070003 | C:\
C:\Windows          | 00000000 | 80070003 | C:\Windows
                    | 00000000 | 80070003 | ::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}
This PC             | 80070002 | 80070003 | 
MyComputerFolder    | 80070002 | 00000000 | ::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}
Recycle Bin         | 80070002 | 80070003 | 
RecycleBinFolder    | 80070002 | 00000000 | ::{645FF040-5081-101B-9F08-00AA002F954E}
Libraries           | 80070002 | 00000000 | ::{031E4825-7B94-4DC3-B131-E946B44C8DD5}
OneDrive            | 80070002 | 80070003 | 
Libraries\Documents | 80070002 | 80070002 | 
Network             | 80070002 | 80070003 | 
NetworkPlacesFolder | 80070002 | 00000000 | ::{F02C1A0D-BE21-4350-88B0-7367FC96EF3C}
Startup             | 80070002 | 00000000 | C:\Users\Anders\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

On Windows 8 `SHCreateItemFromParsingName` calls `SHParseDisplayName` (with `STR_PARSE_AND_CREATE_ITEM` and `STR_PARSE_TRANSLATE_ALIASES`) so even Microsoft have trouble separating parsing and display names in their API.

If you want to stay away from undocumented interfaces then you would have to add a third pass where you check the known folder display names. Or alternatively as Raymond Chen suggests in the comments; parse every path component manually against item display names in that `IShellFolder`.

Answer (score 4):

> It would be interesting to debug Explorer and see how it does it.

begin from windows 7 shell use next undocumented interface (until it unchanged from win 7 up to latest win 10)

```
MIDL_INTERFACE("88DF9332-6ADB-4604-8218-508673EF7F8A") IShellUrl : public IUnknown
{
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE ParseFromOutsideSource(PCWSTR,DWORD);
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetUrl(PWSTR,DWORD);
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE SetUrl(PCWSTR,DWORD);
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetDisplayName(PWSTR,DWORD);
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetPidl(ITEMIDLIST_ABSOLUTE * *);
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE SetPidl(ITEMIDLIST_ABSOLUTE const *);
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE SetPidlAndArgs(ITEMIDLIST_ABSOLUTE const *,PCWSTR);
    virtual PWSTR STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetArgs();
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE AddPath(ITEMIDLIST_ABSOLUTE const *);
    virtual void STDMETHODCALLTYPE SetCancelObject(ICancelMethodCalls *);
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE StartAsyncPathParse(HWND,PCWSTR,DWORD,ICancelMethodCalls *);
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetParseResult();
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE SetRequestID(int);
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetRequestID(int *);
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE SetNavFlags(int,int);
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetNavFlags(long *);
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE Execute(struct IShellNavigationTarget *,int *,DWORD);
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE SetCurrentWorkingDir(ITEMIDLIST_ABSOLUTE const *);
    virtual void STDMETHODCALLTYPE SetMessageBoxParent(HWND);
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetPidlNoGenerate(ITEMIDLIST_ABSOLUTE * *);
    virtual DWORD STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetStandardParsingFlags(BOOL);
};

class DECLSPEC_UUID("4BEC2015-BFA1-42FA-9C0C-59431BBE880E") ShellUrl;
```

we can use it for parse display names like `Recycle Bin`, `This PC`, etc.. (*IFileOpenDialog* dialog use it)

we can use it synchronous or asynchronous. for synchronous need call

`ParseFromOutsideSource(L"your name", flags = GetStandardParsingFlags(0))`

if this call is ok, we can get and use `ITEMIDLIST_ABSOLUTE*` by call `GetPidl` (when no longer need free it by `ILFree`) also if file system path exist  can get it by `GetUrl` otherwise original name returned.

also possible use asynchronous parsing - you need call `StartAsyncPathParse` - pass own hwnd and optional `ICancelMethodCalls` interface. when operation finished shell post `RegisterWindowMessage(L"AC_ParseComplete")` (*`wParam == IShellUrl*, lParam == 0`*) to your window. you can get final status by call `GetParseResult()` and if it ok - use `GetPidl`

code example for synchronous parsing

```
HRESULT ParsePath(PCWSTR path, IShellItem **ppsi)
{
    IShellUrl* pShUrl;

    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(ShellUrl), NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pShUrl));

    if (hr == S_OK)
    {
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr = pShUrl->ParseFromOutsideSource(path, pShUrl->GetStandardParsingFlags(TRUE))))
        {
            ITEMIDLIST_ABSOLUTE *pidl;

            if (SUCCEEDED(hr = pShUrl->GetPidl(&pidl)))
            {
                hr = SHCreateItemFromIDList(pidl, IID_PPV_ARGS(ppsi));

                //WCHAR sz[MAX_PATH];
                //if (SUCCEEDED(pShUrl->GetUrl(sz, RTL_NUMBER_OF(sz)))) DbgPrint(">%S\n", sz);

                ILFree(pidl);
            }
        }

        pShUrl->Release();
    }

    return hr;
}

void tt(PCWSTR path)
{
    IShellItem *psi;

    if (0 <= ParsePath(path, &psi))
    {
        PWSTR szName;

        if (S_OK == psi->GetDisplayName(SIGDN_NORMALDISPLAY, &szName))
        {
            DbgPrint("NORMALDISPLAY>%S\n", szName);
            CoTaskMemFree(szName);
        }

        if (S_OK == psi->GetDisplayName(SIGDN_FILESYSPATH, &szName))
        {
            DbgPrint("FILESYSPATH>%S\n", szName);
            CoTaskMemFree(szName);
        }

        psi->Release();
    }
}

void tt()
{
    if (0 <= CoInitialize(0))
    {
        tt(L"Recycle Bin");
        tt(L"Startup");
        CoUninitialize();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For Windows 10 IShellUrl GUID is different:
("4F33718D-BAE1-4F9B-96F2-D2A16E683346")