# Explorer ignores ParseDisplayName in Shell Namespace Extension

Tags: windows, explorer, windows-shell, shell-namespace-extension

I am writing a Shell Namespace Extension.

How may I force explorer to access (and open) items that are not enumerated with `IShellFolder::EnumObjects` by typing their parsing name in the address bar?

---

I have seen `SFGAO_NONENUMERATED` flag which I believe is used to mark such items (so in theory it should be possible, otherwise why do one need this flag?). I don't want to use `SFGAO_HIDDEN` or `SFGAO_SYSTEM` because such items could be seen nevertheless.

I am expecting explorer to call `IShellFolder::ParseDisplayName` with absolute or at least relative path to the item requested. But instead it is calling `IShellFolder::ParseDisplayName` only for the first segment of the parsing name (basically the first folder's parsing name). After this explorer queries content of each sub folder via `IShellFolder::EnumObjects` and calls `IShellFolder::GetDisplayNameOf` to get both display and parsing name of each item enumerated.

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42966489/how-to-use-shcreateitemfromparsingname-with-names-from-the-shell-namespace#comment73029116_42966489) comment from Raymond Chen I understood that it is normal for explorer to rely on both display and parsing names to retrieve the item requested in the address bar. But the biggest issue here is that my items (that I want to obtain) are not enumerated. So explorer does not know about their existence.

Comment: EnumObjects (required) and ParseDisplayName (optional) implementations must be consistent. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Just as described: I want some objects not to be visible in explorer but accessible via specifying parsing name in address bar. Hidden or system objects are not a solution since user may see them I explorer is set to show hidden / system objects.

Comment: That won't work with standard Shell code as a client of your extension.